# How to turn off pemissions in "Other app capabilities" of Google Play Services?

Tags: permissions, google-play-services

There are "Other app capabilities" permissions in Google Play Services. It can be reached by:

1. Open the Android **Settings** app
2. Select **Application**
3. Select **All applications**
4. Select **Google Play services**
5. Select **Permissions**
6. Select **App permissions**
7. From the overflow menu, (three dots menu︙)

   select **All permissions**

It's located at the bottom of the page when you scroll down. One of them is "Full access to the network", "...Not necessary for sending data to the internet, as the means to send data to the internet is provided by the browser or other apps".

I don't know how to turn off "Other app capabilities" in Google Play services.

I searched but could not find it.

Does anyone know how to turn it off?

Comment: I assume this is a translation problem as the Android app settings do not contain an entry named "Authority". May be do you mean the page "Permissions"? If this page is opened it has in the three dots menu an entry "All permissions". And if you scroll down to the end in section "Other app capabilities" there is an entry "receive data from the Internet". Is this what you are talking about?

Comment: I have included your comment and the corrected translation into your question. Have you read [Google Play Services required permissions](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/196248/2241) and the answers?

Comment: Yes,It's "Permissions".Yes,It's three dots menu︙."receive data from the Internet"(Allows the app to receive cloud-device messages sent from the app's services. Using this service will result in data communication. Malicious(or Evil) applications may cause excessive data traffic), there is that too. I want to turn off that permission as well. The first thing I said was "Full access to the network",There is a that in "Other app capabilities"

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/196248/google-play-services-required-permissionsを先程読みました(I just read the link).I had the same problem and doubts before(Until a few years ago).That are physical activity,Camera, Files & Media, Body Sensors, Microphone, Location, Call History, Phone, Nearby Devices, Contacts, SMS.Yes,Previously they were forced on.But now only "physical activity" is forced on.

Comment: I looked at the link.It seems like other people have similar problems.